# Separating data within a foreach datarow

Tags: c#, foreach, datarow

I need to display my data like this:

**Tasks Due**

- 1/1/2015 - Task #1
- 2/1/2015 - Task #3
- 3/1/2015 - Task #4

**No Due Date**

- Task #2
- Task #5

I need to separate out tasks that have a due date and tasks that do not (dueDate field is null if no date). I was able to do it but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it. Is there a way to do this so that if there are no tasks with no due date I could hide the "No Due Date" header?

```
Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> userEmailList = new Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string email = row["AssignedToEmail"].ToString();

    if (!userEmailList.ContainsKey(email))
    {
        userEmailList.Add(email, new List<DataRow>());
    }
    userEmailList[email].Add(row);
}
string dueDate = "";
foreach (string emailAddy in userEmailList.Keys)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<html><head></head><body>");
    sb.Append("<h2>Tasks Due</h2><ul>");
    foreach (DataRow row in userEmailList[emailAddy])
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["dueDate"].ToString()))
        {
            dueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dueDate"]).ToShortDateString();
            sb.AppendFormat("<li><strong>{0}</strong> - {1}</li>", dueDate, row["details"].ToString());
        }
    }
    sb.Append("</ul><h2>No Due Date</h2><ul>");
    foreach (DataRow row in userEmailList[emailAddy])
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["dueDate"].ToString()))
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", row["details"].ToString());
        }
    }
    sb.Append("</ul></body><html>");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two StringBuilders could also remove the need to have two loops

```
    foreach (string emailAddy in userEmailList.Keys)
    {
        StringBuilder sbDue = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbNotDue = new StringBuilder();
        sbDue.Append("<html><head></head><body>");
        sbDue.Append("<h2>Tasks Due</h2><ul>");
        foreach (DataRow row in userEmailList[emailAddy])
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["dueDate"].ToString()))
            {
                dueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dueDate"]).ToShortDateString();
                sbDue.AppendFormat("<li><strong>{0}</strong> - {1}</li>", dueDate, row["details"].ToString());
            }
            else
                 sbNotDue.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", row["details"].ToString());
        }
        if(sbNotDue.Length > 0)
        {
           sbNotDue.Insert("<h2>No Due Date</h2><ul>");
           sbDue.Append(sbNotDue.ToString());
        } 

        sbDue.Append("</ul></body><html>");
    }
```